# Windows 7 installation - 100MB additional partition

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I have a problem when I try to install Windows 7. I have two hard disk (Disk0, Disk1).

When I try to install windows it always reserve about 100 MB on Disk 1 while I'm installing Windows on Disk0. When installation is finished, I found that this partition contains nothing , but it has about 100 MB reserved.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

> It contains boot files and recovery info. If you delete it you will no longer be able to boot you computer. If you want to see what's in there you need to go to Disk Management and give it a letter. It will then appear in explorer.
>
> It can be avoided entirely by pre-partitioning and pre-formatting your drive

Taken from [Here](http://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/10408-whats-100mb-partition-can-i-delete.html)

Comment: ok, Thank you very much, but I just want to know why he reserve this space on a different hard disk , I have installed windows in Disk0 so I think he should create that in Disk0 , but what going on that he create it in Disk1

Answer (score 0):

The 100 MB is actually created specifically to support disk wide Bitlocker.